# Why does my PHP MYSQL Query not work with SUM?

Tags: php, mysql

I don't get it.

This PHP - MYSQL query does work:

```
      $sql = mysqli_prepare($conn, 'SELECT O.*
                                      FROM OFFER O
                                            LEFT JOIN EVENT E ON E.OFFER_ID = O.KEY_ID
                                            LEFT JOIN BOOKING B ON B.EVENT_ID = E.KEY_ID
                                    WHERE O.KEY_ID = ? ');  

      $sql->bind_param('i', $keyId);
```

With SUM statement it doesn't work:

```
  $sql = mysqli_prepare($conn, 'SELECT O.*,
                                       SUM(CASE WHEN B.KEY_ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS BOOKING_COUNT
                                  FROM OFFER O
                                        LEFT JOIN EVENT E ON E.OFFER_ID = O.KEY_ID
                                        LEFT JOIN BOOKING B ON B.EVENT_ID = E.KEY_ID
                                WHERE O.KEY_ID = ? ');  

  $sql->bind_param('i', $keyId);
```

Error message: 
**Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in ..snippet-ops.php(361) : eval()'d code:107**

The query works in phpmyadmin though.Does anyone know why?

EDIT: SOLVED: The accepted Answer contains the solution in the comments (turning on report and a GROUP BY solved the issue.

EDIT2: When downgrading a question it would be good to know why otherwise the downgrade is useless.

Comment: Maybe the prepare statement has a problem with case statements. Try this: SUM(IF(B.KEY_ID IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS BOOKING_COUNT

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I get the same error.

Comment: Execute the query directly in MySQL

Comment: What do you mean? I can execute the same query in phpMyAdmin sucessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try surrounding your query string with double quotes instead of single quotes. Beware, that `prepare` might return `false` instead of a statement object. You should check this and react accordingly. Also make sure to close your statement after you're done with it.

Here (not tested):

```
<?php

$sql = "
SELECT O.*, SUM(CASE WHEN B.KEY_ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS BOOKING_COUNT 
FROM OFFER O 
LEFT JOIN EVENT E ON E.OFFER_ID = O.KEY_ID 
LEFT JOIN BOOKING B ON B.EVENT_ID = E.KEY_ID 
WHERE O.KEY_ID = ?
GROUP BY O.KEY_ID";

if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $keyId);
    $stmt->execute();

    // do stuff with $stmt

    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo $stmt->error;
}

?>
```

**UPDATE:** As can be seen in the comments, it was necessary  to group by the column O.KEY_ID, or the `prepare` would return `false`.

Comment: Ok thank you for yoru input. Surrounding with double quotes did not work either.
I then checked my $sql variable after the prepare statement - you are right, I get false back - but why?

Comment: Try checking `$stmt->error` instead of `$conn->error` in the else clause. What does it contain?

Comment: I did the following: I turned on report via mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
Then php log is more chatty: I got this here: "Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'MY_DB.O.KEY_ID'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by in "

Comment: I solved it by adding GROUP BY O.KEY_ID at the end of the statement.

Comment: see updated answer. would you mind accepting the answer too? :)

Comment: Accepted because it led me to the solution :)